# Change build.gradle template file to include libraries upon creation

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Whenever I made a new android studio project, I usually have to add the same handful of libraries to my build.gradle file.  To save time, is there a way to modify the template for the generated build.gradle file to include these libraries?  I found a way to do that for gradlew and for the parent gradle file but not for the app itself.  Any help is appreciated.

Cheers!